# How to Add a Splash Screen(Image or gradient color) to a React Native Application

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm new in react native, I need to implement splash screen (image or gradient color) on react native application for IOS and Android.
I implement only color and icon, but I want gradient color, but if it not possible I want to upload image.
I use react-native-bootsplash.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This npm package [react-native-splash-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen) has all the steps to implement a splash screen

Comment: I use react-native-bootsplash

Comment: @Manko Is it better than react-native-splash-screen? Or ant major differences?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ImageBackground>` tag for image or if you want using color then take main `<view>` and give some `style` to main `<view>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).